# URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs) com_google_firebase_crashlytics_mappingfile.xml

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, crashlytics

I have seen that the file that is generated automatically by crashlytics located in res(generated)/values/ com_google_firebase_crashlytics_mappingfile.xml has an error and I don't know why.

The error is in the line of code: `resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`

And the error says: URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs)

The app is working perfectly and crashlytics is working okay (also let you know that I am initializing Firefase manually as I have the follownig in Android Manifest:

```
<provider
    android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.firebaseinitprovider"
    tools:node="remove"
    />
```

As I have said the app works well, but I have doubts why http://schemas.android.com/tools is highlighted in red...